# how do i return the info from the named array with a for each loop. WordPress-Plugin

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

this is the array the array is way bigger but this is to show it a bit beter

```
$products = [
    ['product_code' => 106, 'product_name' => 'ESET NOD32 Antivirus'],
    ['product_code' => 107, 'product_name' => 'ESET Endpoint Antivirus'],
    ['product_code' => 108, 'product_name' => 'ESET Cyber Security'],
```

this is the function, i really dont know i just tried something

```
function add_products_callback()
{
    include('includes/products.php');
        foreach ($products as $product){
            echo "Product Code:" . "<br>";
        }
}
```

[here is an image of how it comes out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FNdr.png)
but i want it to come out like,

Product Code: 106 
Product Code: 107 
Product Code: 108

Comment: `echo "Product Code:" . $product['product_code'] . "<br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreach function puts each value in every round into the same variable. It gets overwritten per round. 
Just get the variable of the round and echo the value at the key "product_code".

```
include('includes/products.php');

    function add_products_callback()
    {
            foreach ($products as $product){
                echo "Product Code:" .$product["product_code"]. "<br>";
            }
    }
```